# How to animate line-drawing in Fabric

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

It is not very hard to animate line-drawing in clear Canvas, but i don't understand how do it in Fabric .
For example i got this line :

```
var L = new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 200], {
    left: 170,
    top: 150,
    stroke: 'red'
})
```

and i need that one of its end started to continue till next point ( like a pencil drawing the line ). 
I know that there is a function 'animate' , but with

```
L.animate('left', 50, {
onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
duration: 3000
});
```

my line only changes its top-left coordinates , not changing itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the animate property as object in first argument

```
{
  x2: 200,
  y2: 200
}
```

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var line = new fabric.Line([50,100,50,100],{
  left: 170,
  top: 150,
  stroke: 'red'
});
canvas.add(line);
line.animate({
  x2: 200,
  y2: 200
}, {
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
  onComplete: function() {
    line.setCoords();
  },
  duration: 3000
});
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```