# FabricJS Animate Path

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to smoothly animate a path in FabricJS. I've seen examples of [how to animate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199458/how-to-animate-line-drawing-in-fabric), but nothing about animating paths.

I've been able to iterate through an array of path points to get something functioning, but it's choppy and doesn't work well:

```
function animateLine(pathArray) {
  var pathString = '';
  var directionLine;

  pathArray.forEach((item, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      pathString = pathString + item + ',';

      canvas.remove(directionLine);
      directionLine = new fabric.Path(pathString, {
        fill: '',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        objectCaching: false
      });
      canvas.add(directionLine);

    }, i * 20);
  });

}

animateLine(pathString);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/lorkel/Lmu8sk4x/8/).

I'm looking to do something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaska/yFJ4e/), but it uses Raphael and I'm hoping to not have to switch libraries.

Comment: Hello, did you get a solution to this problem? If yes can you share?

Comment: @JithinKs yes, it's in the answer below with a Fiddle example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to figure out a solution with help from one of the mods pointing me to `strokeDashOffset`.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var pathArray = "M78.2,0.1c0,0,9.4,79.1,2.3,117  c-4.5,24.1-31.8,106.2-56.3,108.7c-12.7,1.3-24.2-11.9-16.5-15.5C15,207,40.2,231.1,19,261.7c-9.8,14.1-24.7,31.9-12.5,44.9  c11.3,12,53-36.8,59.2-23.8c8.6,18-40.8,23-28,49.2c14.7,30.4,21.6,39.9,48,58.5c31.3,22,147,66.2,147.2,149.5";

var path = new fabric.Path(pathArray, {
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
  strokeDashOffset: 0
});
canvas.add(path);

function animatePath(path) {
    path.animate('strokeDashOffset', '-=3', {
    duration: 100,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: function(){
        animatePath(path)
    }
    });
}

animatePath(path);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lorkel/Lmu8sk4x/28/)